# Getting the output of Spark org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset#show() as a String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there any way to retrieve the output of `Dataset#show()` as String?

The following prints it to stdout, but I am wondering if I could retrieve it as a String and log it somewhat better:

```
val foobarData: DataFrame = ...

println("+++ foobarData.show(): +++") 
foobarData.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it currently except by providing an "accessor", i.e. a piece of code in the `org.apache.spark.sql` package which would use package-private API:

```
package org.apache.spark.sql

object ShowAccessor {
  def show(ds: Dataset[_]): String = ds.showString(20)
}
```

You may want to be able to specify a different set of parameters (`showString` has two more parameters with default values), but the general idea remains the same.

Alternatively, you can do the above with reflection, but it would require more code (especially with Scala reflection), so I personally prefer the accessors approach.

Unfortunately, this approach probably won't work with Java 9+ (of course, once Spark finally supports it), because Java 9+ enforces module boundaries much more strictly that Java 8 and older. In this case accessing this API using reflection will probably be necessary.

As a side note, I was really surprised when I found out that the public Spark API does not provide `show()` outputting to a string. I see no sensible reason to do so, and it gives a lot of inconvenience in case you want to e.g. print the dataframe using an SLF4J logger.